# My reputation is being reduced by two on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, reputation

From yesterday onwards my reputation on Stack Overflow is adding in a strange way.

For example:

- One of my questions is upvoted. I should get +5 and it is showing I got +5 but only +3 is added to my total reputation.
- One of my answers is accepted and it shows I got +15 reputation but only +13 is added to my total reputation.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Did you check whether you had down votes?  It has happened to me that I got a +8 which was actually +10 - 2.

Comment: @Willeke no down votes..0 votes..and answer is accepted..and showing +15 at top but only +13 is added..

Comment: Probably suggested edits you made on posts that have since been deleted. Make sure the "show removed posts" checkbox is checked at the bottom of the reputation page in your profile.

Comment: @Sachu I meant down votes against any answer you ever gave.

Comment: @Sachu what exactly do you mean "but only +3 is added to my total reputation"? How can you tell that? Based on what?

Comment: @ShadowWizard let say i had 2000 reputation then today one of my answer was selected as best answer so +15 should added..but my total reputation only become 2013..but it should be 2015 right?

Comment: Well, there's no indication in your profile, maybe a moderator can see something that we missed.